# Read data from a client socket seems miss bytes (from java to python)

Tags: java, python, network-programming, protocol-buffers

#### Background

I have recently just started to learn networking and google's protocol buffers to build a communication between my java client to a python server. Sending message from my python server to java client works perfect, but the reverse way (from java to python) was always failed.

#### Problem

After checking the length of message from both sides, I have found the receiver(python) missing some of the bytes transferred by the java code,

> java side:
>   12 28 08 0b 12 24 15 00 00 80 3f 1a 1b 09 00 00 00 00 00 00 f0 3f 11 00 00 00 00 00 00 f0 3f 19 00 00 00 00 00 00 f0 3f 22 00
>   python side:
>   12 28 08 0b 12 24 15 00 00 80 3f 1a 1b 09 00 00 00 00 00 00 f0 3f 11 00 00 00 00 00 00 f0 3f

As you can see, the last 10 bytes is missing. I could not figure out the problem.

#### Codes

The following is my java code,

```
// Both Message and UPDATEs are message types I defined in my .proto file
Message message = Message.newBuilder()
                        .setUpdate(UPDATEs.newBuilder()
                        .setTimeStamp(11)
                        .addUpdates(state))
                        .build();
//System.out.println(message.toString());
System.out.println(message.toByteArray().length); // result -> 42
//System.out.println(byteArrayToHex(message.toByteArray()));
try {   
    OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
    message.writeDelimitedTo(outputStream);     
    System.out.println("Sending finished.");
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("SteerCommunicator_sendCarData(OutputStream output): " + e.toString());
    System.exit(0);
}
```

and my python code,

```
def server_loop():
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print "Listening at port {}".format(PORT)
try:
    server.bind(("localhost", PORT))
except:
    print "Unable to listen on the Port" + PORT
    sys.exit()

server.listen(10)

while True:
    client_socket, addr = server.accept()
    print "Received Message from Client {}:{}".format(addr[0],str(addr[1]))
    msg = client_socket.recv(1024)
    print len(msg) # result -> 32
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried outputStream.flush() because it can be buffered and be never sent? Also in python loop, you should read data from client_socket in infinite loop, until socket is closed, because data may arrive in different packets/messages.

Comment: @DmitryZvorygin Oh, thanks. The problem indeed is I never put my receiver into a infinite loop..

Comment: @DmitryZvorygin BTW, should I also enclose my method of reading data in a while loop in java? And ... could some help me close this question...

Comment: If you want to close the question, click on the "delete" link.

Comment: yes, if you read anything in Java you have to be aware that inputStream.read(byte[] buffer), doesn't promise to read "full" buffer, but reads at least one byte and returns number of bytes read as return value(don't know Python API, but assume it's the same). Also, as @stephen-c suggested bellow, you should close sockets/streams once you are done(closing stream usually indirectly flushes all the buffers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the diagnosis that the stream is not being flushed is correct, then here is the solution:

```
    try (OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream()) {
        message.writeDelimitedTo(outputStream);     
        System.out.println("Sending finished.");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // SEE NOTES!!
        System.err.println("blah blah" + e.toString());
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

Explanation: by using *try-with-resources*, we ensure that the resource is always closed as the block exits, no matter *how* it exits.  This has two benefits:

1. It ensures that the stream is flushed
2. It ensures that you don't leak the resource (i.e. the associated `FileDescriptor`).  Resource leaks can cause various unrelated I/O activity to fail ... later on ... if the GC doesn't get a chance to clean up the mess first.

NOTES:

1. Calling `System.exit(...)` in the depths of your code is a bad idea.  It preempts other possible approaches to recovery, and makes your code harder to extend and/or reuse.
2. If you catch and report an exception, you should also report the stacktrace ... somewhere.
3. A better strategy would be to declare `IOException` as thrown by the enclosing method, and catch / report / recover at a higher level.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!